# Recent search list functionality with Swift or Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a text field into which a user types data and presses a button to perform an action. The next time the user goes to do this I would like to present something similar to the image below, where a table view containing the recently entered data is visible (in a tableview?) and can be tapped on to use the data in that cell.

[image: example from the Hopper app]

Could someone advice me on how to achieve this functionality as I'm not sure where to begin?

Comment: This question is way too broad.  Do you have a more specific programming question?

Answer (score 0):

Simple feature to add. Just add a `NSMutableArray` and keep adding searches that the user makes to that array.

Then every time the user taps on the search bar, create a `UITableView` and populate it with the search strings from the array.

You can then use the table view delegate methods to get the string from the array and add it to the search bar, depending on which cell is tapped.

Comment: Great. Thanks! I'll try this out and post my progress.